# Page redirects to itself

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to add an user for the login page but it keeps redirecting even though there is no redirection provided in the code

login.php

```
<?php
include './connect.php';
session_start();
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && (!empty($_POST['username'])) && (!empty($_POST['password']))) {
    $postedUsername = $_POST['username'];
    $postedPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $userDatabaseFind = $database->login->findOne(array('username' => $postedUsername, 'password' => $postedPassword));
    $storedUsername = $userDatabaseFind['username'];
    $storedPassword = $userDatabaseFind['password'];

    if (($postedUsername == $storedUsername) && ($postedPassword == $storedPassword)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $storedUsername;


        if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin'){

            session_regenerate_id();
             header('location:printDetail.php');
            }
        else{
                session_regenerate_id();
                header('location:welcome.php');
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Error';
    }
}
```

printDetail.php

```
<?php
require './connect.php';
require './login.php';

//SEARCHING ACROSS THE COLLECTIONS IN THE DATABASE

$printDetailCollections = $database->details;
$printDetailCursor = $printDetailCollections->find();

//INITIALIZE THE VALUE TO ZERO SO IT CAN GO THROUGH THE DATABASE

$i = 0;

//USERNAME AND PASSWORD ARE CHECKED IF IT IS ASSIGNRD THEN THE SESSION IS DISPLAYED

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !(empty($_SESSION['username']))) {

    //LOOP FOR TRAVERSING ACROSS THE DATABASE

    foreach ($printDetailCursor as $doc) {
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    header('location:index.html');
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            th, td {
                padding: 15px;
            }
            body{
                background-image: url(images/16386858141_65a65879cd_b.jpg);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;

            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                window.onload = $('#table').hide();
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Business card Management</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="addUser.php">Add entry</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Delete entry</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Second Name</th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($printDetailCursor as $printDetailDocument) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                echo (json_decode($printDetailDocument['First Name']));
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                echo (json_decode($printDetailDocument['Second Name']));
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                echo (json_decode($printDetailDocument['Company Name']));
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                echo (json_decode($printDetailDocument['Designation']));
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have 3 collections in the mongodb login and details.The add user tries to access the login collection for adding the user

addUser.php

```
<?php

    include './connect.php';
$username = NULL;
$password = NULL;
$confPassword = NULL;
$passwordError = "";
$userEntryCollection = NULL;

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !(empty($_SESSION['username']))) {
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $userEntryCollection = $database->login;
        if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['confPassword'])) {
            $confPassword = $_POST['confPassword'];
        }
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
    if ($password != $confPassword) {
        $passwordError = "Your passwords doesnot match";
    } else {
        $userEntry = array(
            "username" => $username,
            "password" => $password,
        );
        $userEntryCollection->insert($userEntry);
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css>
        <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .col-lg-10{
                position: relative;
                width: 350px;
                border-radius: 25px;

            }
            form{
                position: absolute;
                top: 10%;
                left: 40%;
            }
            body{
                background-image: url(images/16386858141_65a65879cd_b.jpg);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
            }
            form{
                color: black;
            } 

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="printDetail.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left">Back</span></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <form  method="POST" class="col-lg-10" <?php echo $passwordError; ?> >
            <div class="form-group form-inline"><br>
                <label for="firstName">Username</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
            </div>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                <label for="secondName">Password:</label><br>
                <input type=password class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                <label for="secondName">Confirm Password</label><br>
                <input type=password class="form-control" id="confPassword" name="confPassword">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have tried to disable access to the printDetail.php via the URL
and i think that is the main reason for redirection.But couldn't figure out the error in the code

The page gets redirected just by clicking the field of the Username

P.s: i know the password stored this way is insecure

Comment: what's in the `index.php` ?

Comment: it has just the html template for the username and pwd entry nothing else

Comment: Don't you think that `session_regenerate_id();` could be the reason why you don't have a `isset($_SESSION['username'])` in printDetail.php ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I don't think so because `session_regenerate_id()` just regenerates the id and keeps the data.

Comment: OK, @imrealashu, you're right. I re-read the question... So, abhishek, When is the page redirecting? On load of `printDetail.php` or when you click on `<a href="addUser.php">Add entry</a>` ? And what do you mean with *«disable access to the printDetail.php via the URL»* ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette the redirection happens when i try to enter the data in the addUser.php form., and what i meant is _prindDetail.php_ can only be accessed if the $_SESSION['username'] is set and not by accessing the directory via the URL

Comment: So when you submit a new user infos, the page reloads. Do you submit the infos to addUser.php? I suppose yes, because the code to save it to DB is there. After the save, the form is displayed again... Empty. And there is nothing to indicate that the data were saved. Am I close to what you observe?

Comment: NO ! there is no save, the page get redirected even before entering the data.It redirects just by clicking the username field itself @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed your code on my server and I confirm your page redirection problem when trying to input something in the `addUser.php` form...

Your mistake is in these lines:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="printDetail.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left">Back</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You didn't close the ancor for "Back".

The result is all your form and every single elements of the pages (until another ancor... But there is none) are included by the browser in this ancor.
 Then also are "Back" links.
[image]
It is simple as this.

Use [F12] to debug via the console and code inspector, next time...
;)